# PyCrypto not Working on Python 3.2

Tags: python-3.x, pycrypto

I have PyCrypto version 2.6 and I have read from the changelog that 2.4 or later version of PyCrypto Supports Python 3. 
I tried to install it using

```
 # python3 setup.py install
```

**But it gives me this error**

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running build_configure
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
building 'Crypto.Hash._MD2' extension
gcc -pthread -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -fPIC -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python3.2mu -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.2/src/MD2.o
src/MD2.c:31:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu, install `python3-devel` or `python-devel`.

Comment: Blender <code>python3-devel</code> is only available for fedora, mandriva , open suse and Megia Linux 
but for ubuntu has some big list of python3 packages to choose from here is the list http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/precise/python3-defaults

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu, so I don't know the package names by heart. Try installing `python3-dev`.

Comment: Thank you so much Blender I have successfully installed pycrypto thanks to  **python3-dev**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem with pycrypto on python3.3 on Ubuntu 13.04.

Installing `python3.3-dev` package solved the problem.

Try with installing python3.2-dev or similar depending on your distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making this steps :

1. ./configure
2. python setup.py build
3. python setup.py install

hope this will help you ! for me its fine